# RedHat 7.2 how to get stub-32.h

Tags: c++, redhat

I have a 64bit system running RedHat 7.2, I am trying to build a project that requires stub-32.h

This would be located in /usr/include/gnu

However my installation has only these files in the above folder:

```
    -rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1270 Aug 11 06:56 libc-version.h
    -rw-r--r--. 1 root root 4844 Aug 11 06:56 lib-names.h
    -rw-r--r--. 1 root root  604 Aug 11 06:57 stubs-64.h
    -rw-r--r--. 1 root root  384 Aug 11 06:56 stubs.h
```

I've tried various methods to get stubs-32.h installed but keep coming up against the same problems, if I try:

```
    sudo yum install glibc-devel.i686
```

The result is:

```
    Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
    Resolving Dependencies
    --> Running transaction check
    ---> Package glibc-devel.i686 0:2.17-106.el7_2.8 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: glibc = 2.17-106.el7_2.8 for package: glibc-devel-2.17-106.el7_2.8.i686
    --> Processing Dependency: glibc-headers = 2.17-106.el7_2.8 for package: glibc-devel-2.17-106.el7_2.8.i686
    --> Finished Dependency Resolution
    Error: Package: glibc-devel-2.17-106.el7_2.8.i686 (rhel-7-workstation-rpms)
       Requires: glibc = 2.17-106.el7_2.8
       Installed: glibc-2.17-157.el7.i686 (@rhel-7-workstation-rpms)
           glibc = 2.17-157.el7
       Available: glibc-2.17-55.el7.i686 (rhel-7-workstation-rpms)
           glibc = 2.17-55.el7
       Available: glibc-2.17-55.el7_0.1.i686 (rhel-7-workstation-rpms)
           glibc = 2.17-55.el7_0.1
       Available: glibc-2.17-55.el7_0.3.i686 (rhel-7-workstation-rpms)
           glibc = 2.17-55.el7_0.3
       Available: glibc-2.17-55.el7_0.5.i686 (rhel-7-workstation-rpms)
           glibc = 2.17-55.el7_0.5
       Available: glibc-2.17-78.el7.i686 (rhel-7-workstation-rpms)
           glibc = 2.17-78.el7
       Available: glibc-2.17-105.el7.i686 (rhel-7-workstation-rpms)
           glibc = 2.17-105.el7
       Available: glibc-2.17-106.el7_2.1.i686 (rhel-7-workstation-rpms)
           glibc = 2.17-106.el7_2.1
       Available: glibc-2.17-106.el7_2.4.i686 (rhel-7-workstation-rpms)
           glibc = 2.17-106.el7_2.4
       Available: glibc-2.17-106.el7_2.6.i686 (rhel-7-workstation-rpms)
           glibc = 2.17-106.el7_2.6
       Available: glibc-2.17-106.el7_2.8.i686 (rhel-7-workstation-rpms)
           glibc = 2.17-106.el7_2.8
    Error: Package: glibc-devel-2.17-106.el7_2.8.i686 (rhel-7-workstation-rpms)
       Requires: glibc-headers = 2.17-106.el7_2.8
       Installed: glibc-headers-2.17-157.el7.x86_64 (@rhel-7-workstation-rpms)
           glibc-headers = 2.17-157.el7
       Available: glibc-headers-2.17-55.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-workstation-rpms)
           glibc-headers = 2.17-55.el7
       Available: glibc-headers-2.17-55.el7_0.1.x86_64 (rhel-7-workstation-rpms)
           glibc-headers = 2.17-55.el7_0.1
       Available: glibc-headers-2.17-55.el7_0.3.x86_64 (rhel-7-workstation-rpms)
           glibc-headers = 2.17-55.el7_0.3
       Available: glibc-headers-2.17-55.el7_0.5.x86_64 (rhel-7-workstation-rpms)
           glibc-headers = 2.17-55.el7_0.5
       Available: glibc-headers-2.17-78.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-workstation-rpms)
           glibc-headers = 2.17-78.el7
       Available: glibc-headers-2.17-105.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-workstation-rpms)
           glibc-headers = 2.17-105.el7
       Available: glibc-headers-2.17-106.el7_2.1.x86_64 (rhel-7-workstation-rpms)
           glibc-headers = 2.17-106.el7_2.1
       Available: glibc-headers-2.17-106.el7_2.4.x86_64 (rhel-7-workstation-rpms)
           glibc-headers = 2.17-106.el7_2.4
       Available: glibc-headers-2.17-106.el7_2.6.x86_64 (rhel-7-workstation-rpms)
           glibc-headers = 2.17-106.el7_2.6
       Available: glibc-headers-2.17-106.el7_2.8.x86_64 (rhel-7-workstation-rpms)
           glibc-headers = 2.17-106.el7_2.8
    **********************************************************************
    yum can be configured to try to resolve such errors by temporarily enabling
    disabled repos and searching for missing dependencies.
    To enable this functionality please set 'notify_only=0' in /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/search-disabled-repos.conf
    **********************************************************************
    Error: Package: glibc-devel-2.17-106.el7_2.8.i686 (rhel-7-workstation-rpms)
       Requires: glibc = 2.17-106.el7_2.8
       Installed: glibc-2.17-157.el7.i686 (@rhel-7-workstation-rpms)
           glibc = 2.17-157.el7
       Available: glibc-2.17-55.el7.i686 (rhel-7-workstation-rpms)
           glibc = 2.17-55.el7
       Available: glibc-2.17-55.el7_0.1.i686 (rhel-7-workstation-rpms)
           glibc = 2.17-55.el7_0.1
       Available: glibc-2.17-55.el7_0.3.i686 (rhel-7-workstation-rpms)
           glibc = 2.17-55.el7_0.3
       Available: glibc-2.17-55.el7_0.5.i686 (rhel-7-workstation-rpms)
           glibc = 2.17-55.el7_0.5
       Available: glibc-2.17-78.el7.i686 (rhel-7-workstation-rpms)
           glibc = 2.17-78.el7
       Available: glibc-2.17-105.el7.i686 (rhel-7-workstation-rpms)
           glibc = 2.17-105.el7
       Available: glibc-2.17-106.el7_2.1.i686 (rhel-7-workstation-rpms)
           glibc = 2.17-106.el7_2.1
       Available: glibc-2.17-106.el7_2.4.i686 (rhel-7-workstation-rpms)
           glibc = 2.17-106.el7_2.4
       Available: glibc-2.17-106.el7_2.6.i686 (rhel-7-workstation-rpms)
           glibc = 2.17-106.el7_2.6
       Available: glibc-2.17-106.el7_2.8.i686 (rhel-7-workstation-rpms)
           glibc = 2.17-106.el7_2.8
    Error: Package: glibc-devel-2.17-106.el7_2.8.i686 (rhel-7-workstation-rpms)
       Requires: glibc-headers = 2.17-106.el7_2.8
       Installed: glibc-headers-2.17-157.el7.x86_64 (@rhel-7-workstation-rpms)
           glibc-headers = 2.17-157.el7
       Available: glibc-headers-2.17-55.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-workstation-rpms)
           glibc-headers = 2.17-55.el7
       Available: glibc-headers-2.17-55.el7_0.1.x86_64 (rhel-7-workstation-rpms)
           glibc-headers = 2.17-55.el7_0.1
       Available: glibc-headers-2.17-55.el7_0.3.x86_64 (rhel-7-workstation-rpms)
           glibc-headers = 2.17-55.el7_0.3
       Available: glibc-headers-2.17-55.el7_0.5.x86_64 (rhel-7-workstation-rpms)
           glibc-headers = 2.17-55.el7_0.5
       Available: glibc-headers-2.17-78.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-workstation-rpms)
           glibc-headers = 2.17-78.el7
       Available: glibc-headers-2.17-105.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-workstation-rpms)
           glibc-headers = 2.17-105.el7
       Available: glibc-headers-2.17-106.el7_2.1.x86_64 (rhel-7-workstation-rpms)
           glibc-headers = 2.17-106.el7_2.1
       Available: glibc-headers-2.17-106.el7_2.4.x86_64 (rhel-7-workstation-rpms)
           glibc-headers = 2.17-106.el7_2.4
       Available: glibc-headers-2.17-106.el7_2.6.x86_64 (rhel-7-workstation-rpms)
           glibc-headers = 2.17-106.el7_2.6
       Available: glibc-headers-2.17-106.el7_2.8.x86_64 (rhel-7-workstation-rpms)
           glibc-headers = 2.17-106.el7_2.8
     You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
    ** Found 4 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
    ipa-client-4.4.0-12.el7.x86_64 has installed conflicts freeipa-client: ipa-client-4.4.0-12.el7.x86_64
    ipa-client-common-4.4.0-12.el7.noarch has installed conflicts freeipa-client-common: ipa-client-common-4.4.0-12.el7.noarch
    ipa-common-4.4.0-12.el7.noarch has installed conflicts freeipa-common: ipa-common-4.4.0-12.el7.noarch
    ipa-python-compat-4.4.0-12.el7.noarch has installed conflicts freeipa-        python-compat: ipa-python-compat-4.4.0-12.el7.noarch
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Your yum subscriptions seem to have gotten messed up. Try a `yum clean metadata` and then try again.

Comment: Tried that, exactly the same problem.

Comment: Are you subscribed directly to the RHEL yum servers or an internal server?

Comment: Yes, fully licensed and subscribed.

Comment: Might be an issue with their repos then.

Comment: I will contact redhat support, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Developer_Guide/compilers.html

Section: 
3.1.3.6. Using 32-bit compilers on a 64-bit host

I ran:

```
    sudo yum install --skip-broken glibc-devel.i686 libgcc.i686 libstdc++-devel.i686
```

And followed the instructions.  Still no joy.

I have now installed Centos on Virtual box and simply did:

```
    sudo yum install glibc-devel.i686
```

This worked and now I have:

```
    stubs-32.h
```